# Do I have to fetch the object first in order to update a meta-data field in parse.com

Tags: ios, parse-platform

In Parse.com, the help document for [updating an object](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects-updating/iOS) seems to require a query first to retrieve the object before one can update the meta data.

Given that I know the objectId of the object I am updating, do I still have to make this additional call to retrieve everything else about the object before I can send an update call (via saveInBackground)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you do. In order to update an object from parse, you must have a local copy.

In order to make a call to update an object - which can take several forms of `save` or `saveInBackground` or `saveEventually`, etc. - you must first make a query to have a copy of the object.

If you know the objectId, is sounds like you have already run a query on an associated object - why not get the full object then with an `includeKey:` call? https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries-relational/iOS